# Magento 2 Console command by using virtualTypes

Tags: magento2, command, console, di.xml, virtualtype

I tried this solution but the arguments are empty when I debug the command class. It should be possible to create command classes by using a virtualType, no?

**The constructor arguments are empty in Tester\Test\Model\SyncCommandVirtual when I run the command.**

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

<!-- Command List -->
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Console\CommandList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="commands" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="test_command" xsi:type="object">
                    Tester\Test\Model\SyncCommandVirtual
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

    <virtualType name="Tester\Test\Model\SyncCommandVirtual"
                 type="Test\Tester\Command\SyncCommand">
        <arguments>
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">test:tester:sync</item>
            <item name="description" xsi:type="string">Test sync cmd</item>
            <item name="initiator" xsi:type="object">Test\Tester\Model\SupplierASync\Virtual</item>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
```

SyncCommand.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Test\Tester\Command;

use Laminas\Config\Reader\Ini;
use Test\Tester\Model\Initiator;
use Exception;
use InvalidArgumentException;
use Magento\Framework\Console\Cli;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class SyncCommand extends Command
{
    protected string $name;
    protected string $description;
    protected Initiator $initiator;

    public function __construct(
        Initiator $initiator,
        $description,
        $name = ''
    ) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->description = $description;
        $this->initiator = $initiator;

        parent::__construct($name);
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        try {
            $output->writeln('hello');
            $this->initiator->run();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $output->writeln('<error>' . $e->getMessage() . '</error>');

            return Cli::RETURN_FAILURE;
        }

        return Cli::RETURN_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```